# The smart card is not responding to a reset

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader, pcsc

I have been working of the read / write operation of smart cards, I believe my card is sle_4428 and I am using HID OMNIKEY 3121 USB Card Reader. The problem is that when I enter card in card reader my program responds as **the smart card is not responding to a reset** with error code **0x80100066**, instead of connecting the card and getting **ATR**...

[EDIT] It works fine if I do only the read operation. When I do the write operation and then reinsert the card it stops responding, giving the above message. The APDU command I use to write is: `FF D6 00 00 #(01 02)`

Comment: Have you tried a different card?

Comment: Yeah, I tried different card, at first it was detected and I read/write the data successfully, then again, after re-inserting, it stopped responding giving the same error message as above.

Comment: Always check the length which you are sending with your commands..

Comment: @shadygoneinsane, actually it works fine if I do only the read operation. When I do the write operation and then reinsert the card it stops responding, giving the above message....APDU commad I use to Write is: FF D6 00 00 #( 01 02)

Comment: We are also having problem with HID OMNIKEY 5421 reset. I try looking into HID omnikey workbench tool and its dll's. I found method which is "WAntennaControl". With this method you can properly cold reset smart card. Try out workbench tool and do reset from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that HID Omnikey failes to properly "cold" reset smart card.

With the following Java code-snipped, you can reset HID Omnikey reader CL.

```
import jnasmartcardio.Smartcardio;

import javax.smartcardio.*;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class OMNIKEYConfiguration {

public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getInstance("PC/SC", null, new Smartcardio());

    String terminalName = "OMNIKEY CardMan 5x21-CL 0";
    CardTerminal terminal = factory.terminals().getTerminal(terminalName);

    // Connect directly to reader
    Card card = terminal.connect("DIRECT");

    int code = 3224092; // #define IOCTL_CCID_ESCAPE SCARD_CTL_CODE(3500)
    byte[] command = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("0300"); // 0300 - ON; 0301 - OFF
    byte[] resp = card.transmitControlCommand(code, command);
    System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(resp));

    card.disconnect(true);
}
}
```

Use command "0x0300" to turn ON antenna, otherwise use "0x0301" to turn OFF antenna.

For cold reset call OFF and then ON commands.